# implement Payment Gateways to Ecommerce

Tags: php, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment, silverstripe

I've built an Ecommerce site in Silverstripe and I'm new to this, sorry if I ask something silly. I'm just wondering how do I implement payment gateways to the Ecommerce site in Silverstripe? Do you have any good tutorials that I can follow?

Thank you very much. By the way I'm choosing DPS as the gateway.

Any recommendations for me to start this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to start by looking at the Payment module for SilverStripe.

http://www.silverstripe.org/payment-module/

https://github.com/silverstripe-labs/silverstripe-payment

Comment: For Demo:
 Front End : http://demo.aspxcommerce.com/ 
 Back End  : http://demoadmin.aspxcommerce.com/
 
 New Features: http://www.aspxcommerce.com/What-is-New.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion payment gateway these days provides so much facilities that all we need to do is to redirect user to the payment gateway with certain attributes like amount,curreency and some other attributes being required by the gateway.

once payment is authorized payment gateway redirect user back to your page.Now almost all payment gateway work in two ways

1. Synchronized call
2. ASynchronized call

in the second method you have to provide some entry point to the gateway where it will send you the all required information about payment.
Once you have everything all you need is to do final checkout process for the user.Beside the `silverstripe` payment module i will suggest you to go through `DPS` documentation as they might have shown some samples how you can communicate with them and what they expect from you in the request what its structure should be and what they will send back once user done with payment,response structure etc.

I tend to follow this approach once we decide the payment gateway go through there documentation set up a test account with them and than start playing around.